# How to switch between two disks "quite fast" without exposing them to eachother?

Tags: hard-drive, remote, privacy

Let's say that I'm working remotely on my private PC in my Home (PC is standing next to me)

I'd want to have

- One disk for my private things
- Second one for job, only.

When I'm working - I'm using 2nd one, then after job I'm using 1st one.

Both disks have an OS installed and they're independent.

**I'd want to avoid opening case and reconnecting cables everytime I want to use "different setup"**, but I'd want to be 100% sure that when I'm e.g on my private disk, then my job disk is non-existent / not accessible (something like turned off)

Basically working 7-15, switching to "private disk" as easy / fast as possible but while being safe - no access/leaks from private to job nor from job to private.

I thought that disabling it at BIOS level would be the most comfortable / fastest way to achieve that, is that true or even possible?

I have NVME M2 2280 and SATA 3 SSD

Comment: Do you need to be able to switch disks while working remotely?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator No, I'm fine with restarting PC. I'm working remotely, but PC is next to me

Comment: It would make your question more clear to either state that, or remove the bit about working remotely. Welcome to Super User, BTW.

Comment: You're right, my bad on that. I clarified that

Comment: I would recommend you encrypt your entire personal drive, and then when booting from the work drive, you won't be able to access your personal one unless you explicitly unlock it. Of course, a malicious software could still wipe it, but your data would not be at risk. Taking backups in the 3-2-1 fashion would virtually remove any risk of losing your data in this case

Comment: @QuickishFM What if I had an some malware on private disk, wouldnt that put risk on my job disk during private disk usage?

Comment: @Axelly, Yes, of course, if the work drive was also unencrypted. You would have to power them off to make them completely inaccessible, perhaps using disk management, or even in the BIOS as you mentioned.

Comment: Like @QuickishFM said, the only reliable software-specific way would be to encrypt the drives. However, you should be aware that if the job requires specific privacy concerns then you will want to use completely separate hardware, don't even share the video card. Over the last few years there has been an increase in malware targeting accessory firmware and the malware persists regardless of OS, and can be used to abuse the device even after wiping and reloading the OS on a factory-new drive.

Comment: @shawn I've heard about quite a few ways for malware to achieve persistence, but hijacking the _video card firmware_ was a new one to me. The only similar attack I am aware of is targeting the HDD's fw (which is scary enough!). Any chance you have a link with further info on that? A quick search only brings up HDD fw hacking as well.

Comment: @Entropy0 Google` firmware hacking CIA` or `vault 7 firmware hacking`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem: keeping job os and personal os on separate drives.
Entering into uefi setup (aka bios) at each switch is not such convenient (even on Asus boards when you have "favorites" menu entries), as it cannot be controlled any other way but entering there, and this requires additional reboot.

And I have found quite a good solution - using a sata bay like this:

[image: sata bay OImaster]

It allows you to quickly insert and eject any drive.

Unfortunately, It seems there is no way to disable ("eject") an m.2 ssd (please comment if I am wrong). So I think the best way is to replace your m.2 ssd to usual sata ssd.

Comment: I have created a separate question regarding disabling m.2 nvme slots: https://superuser.com/questions/1746036/is-it-possible-to-disable-m-2-ssd-without-unscrewing-it