# Is it possible to disable an M.2 SSD without physically unscrewing it?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, pci-express, nvme

I want to be able to "hide" the presence of my M.2 NVMe ssd. For example, it can be useful when experimenting with OS installation to experimental drive, and you want to be sure it wont touch your M.2 drive.

With SATA drives it can be achieved simply by disabling specified SATA port in UEFI setup/BIOS. But what about M.2 NVMe drives? It is not convenient to unscrew it every time.

Is there a standard way to disable M.2 slot? Maybe at least only possible from specific vendors? Because I did not found such setting in my UEFI setup.